# JSON Infiito ao usar o GET @ManyToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, relacionamento, spring-jpa

Eu possuo duas classes, da qual tem um relacionamento @ManyToMany gerando a terceira tabela descrito no código a baixo:

**Card**

```
package br.com.rpgnext.deck.critical.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "cards")
public class Card implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    private String image;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "cards_items", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "card_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "item_id"))
    private Set items;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "YYYY-MM-dd")
    private Date onCreate;

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist(){
        this.onCreate = new Date();
    }

    public Card() {
    }

    public Card(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public Card(String image, Set items) {
        this.image = image;
        this.items = items;
    }

    public Card(String image, Set items, Date onCreate) {
        this.image = image;
        this.items = items;
        this.onCreate = onCreate;
    }

    public Card(Long id, String image, Set items, Date onCreate) {
        this.image = image;
        this.items = items;
        this.onCreate = onCreate;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public Set getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(Set items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public Date getOnCreate() {
        return onCreate;
    }

    public void setOnCreate(Date onCreate) {
        this.onCreate = onCreate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Card card = (Card) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, card.id) &&
                Objects.equals(image, card.image) &&
                Objects.equals(items, card.items) &&
                Objects.equals(onCreate, card.onCreate);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(id, image, items, onCreate);
    }
}
```

**Item**

```
package br.com.rpgnext.deck.critical.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
public class Item implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String description;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="type_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Type type;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "items" )
    private Set cards;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "YYYY-MM-dd")
    private Date onCreate;

    @PrePersist
    void prePersist(){
        this.onCreate = new Date();
    }

    public Item() {
    }

    public Item(Long id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Item(Long id, String title, String description, Type type, Set cards, Date onCreate) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.type = type;
        this.cards = cards;
        this.onCreate = onCreate;
    }

    public Item(String title, String description, Type type, Set cards) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.type = type;
        this.cards = cards;
    }

    public Item(Set cards) {
        this.cards = cards;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(Type type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Set getCards() {
        return cards;
    }

    public void setCards(Set cards) {
        this.cards = cards;
    }

    public Date getOnCreate() {
        return onCreate;
    }

    public void setOnCreate(Date onCreate) {
        this.onCreate = onCreate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Item item = (Item) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, item.id) &&
                Objects.equals(title, item.title) &&
                Objects.equals(description, item.description) &&
                Objects.equals(type, item.type) &&
                Objects.equals(cards, item.cards) &&
                Objects.equals(onCreate, item.onCreate);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, title, description, type, cards, onCreate);
    }
}
```

**Type**

```
package br.com.rpgnext.deck.critical.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Objects;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "types")
public class Type implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String text;
    private String image;

    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.DATE)
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "YYYY-MM-dd")
    private Date onCreate;

    @PrePersist
    void prePersists(){
        this.onCreate = new Date();
    }

    public Type() {
    }

    public Type(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Type type = (Type) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, type.id) &&
                Objects.equals(text, type.text) &&
                Objects.equals(image, type.image) &&
                Objects.equals(onCreate, type.onCreate);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(id, text, image, onCreate);
    }
}
```

Foi tentado usar vários jeitos para que tire o Infinite Loop do JSON, já que ambas as classes tem um List, mas sem sucesso.

@JsonIgnore não resolve, pois ele não vai mostrar o conteúdo que preciso.

**Exemplo de JSON Inserido**

```
{
  "image": "Carta-Critica-001.jpg",
  "items": [
    {"id": 1},
    {"id": 2},
    {"id": 3},
    {"id": 4}
  ]
}
```

**Como gostaria de que voltasse**

```
{
  "image": "Carta-Critica-01.jpg",
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "traqueia esmagada",
      "type": {
        "id": 1,
        "text": "contusão",
        "image": "contution.png"
      },
      "description": "Danos Crítico, e o alvo fica incapacitadoe não pode falar e respirar até receber tratamento."
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "mão perfurada",
      "type": {
        "id": 2,
        "text": "perfurante",
        "image": "piercing.png"
      },
      "description": "Danos Crítico, e o alvo solta o que estiver segurando (1 item) e não pode usar aquele membro até o início de seu próximo turno."
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "testa cortada",
      "type": {
        "id": 3,
        "text": "cortante",
        "image": "sharp.png"
      },
      "description": "Danos Crítico, e o alvo fica cego até o início de seu próximo turno."
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "title": "vulnerabilidade mágica",
      "type": {
        "id": 4,
        "text": "mágico",
        "image": "magic.png"
      },
      "description": "Danos Crítico, e o alvo tem vulnerabilidade a dano mágico até o início de seu próximo turno."
    }
  ]
}
}
```

**Controller**

```
package br.com.rpgnext.deck.critical.controller;

import java.beans.Transient;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import br.com.rpgnext.deck.critical.service.ItemService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import br.com.rpgnext.deck.critical.model.Card;
import br.com.rpgnext.deck.critical.model.Item;
import br.com.rpgnext.deck.critical.model.Type;
import br.com.rpgnext.deck.critical.repository.CardRespository;
import br.com.rpgnext.deck.critical.repository.ItemRepository;
import br.com.rpgnext.deck.critical.repository.TypeRepository;
import br.com.rpgnext.deck.critical.service.CardService;

@RestController
public class CardController {
    @Autowired
    private CardRespository cardRespository;

    @Autowired
    private TypeRepository typeRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ItemRepository itemRepository;

    @Autowired
    private CardService cardService;

    @Autowired
    private ItemService itemService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "card/save", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE )
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity save(@RequestBody Card card){
        Card cardSaved = cardRespository.save(card);
        return new ResponseEntity(cardSaved, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "cards/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity> saveAll(@RequestBody List cards){
        return new ResponseEntity((List) cardRespository.findAll(), HttpStatus.FOUND);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "cards", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity> findAll(){
        return new ResponseEntity((List) cardRespository.findAll(), HttpStatus.FOUND);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "card/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity findById(@PathVariable Long id){
        return new ResponseEntity((cardRespository.findById(id).get()), HttpStatus.FOUND);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "card/random", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity randomCard(){
        List cards = (List) cardRespository.findAll();
        Card card = cardService.randomCard(cards);
        return new ResponseEntity(card, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "card/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity randomNewCard(){
        Card card = new Card();

        for(Long i = 1L; i  allItemsByType = itemRepository.findAllByType(type);
            Item item = itemService.randomItem(allItemsByType);
            //item.setCard(card);
            //card.addItem(item);
        }

        Card cardSaved = cardRespository.save(card);
        return new ResponseEntity(cardSaved, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

Comment: Inclua um exemplo do JSON que você espera como resultado, afim de facilitar o entendimento do seu problema.

Comment: Inclua a classe `Type` na sua pergunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicionar referencia de volta em

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "items")
    public class Item implements Serializable {
        /**
         * 
         */
        @JsonBackReference("items")
        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "items" )
        private Set cards;

    }
```

Em ambos lados

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "cards")
    public class Card implements Serializable{

        @JsonBackReference("cards")
        @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinTable(name = "cards_items", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "card_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "item_id"))
        private Set items;

    }
```

Comment: Funcionou, mas não está aparecendo a lista de items dentro do card.

Comment: Quando o card estiver na lista de items, ele nao deve aparecer, e vice-versa, ai para aparecer em ambas, vc tem que dar o fetch na query

Comment: Poderia me dar um exemplo?

Comment: Para recuperar os cards apos terceiro nivel, sugiro que faca uyma seleção separada

Comment: A sua duvida era em relação ao loop infinito entre os multiplos objetos, agora o que esta falando ja entra em outro contexto

Answer (score 1):

Utilize as anotações `JsonManagedReference` e `JsonBackReference`. Elas são utilizadas para indicar que tais propriedades fazem parte de um relacionamento bidirecional. A primeira deve ser usada na classe "pai", já a segunda na classe "filha".

Na sua classe `Card` adicione a anotação `JsonManagedReference`:

```
//Algum motivo para não parametrizar seu Set (Set<Item>)?
@JsonManagedReference
private Set items;
```

Na sua classe `Item` adicione a anotação `JsonBackReference`:

```
//Algum motivo para não parametrizar seu Set (Set<Card>)?
@JsonBackReference
private Set items;
```

Comment: Eu tenho o custume de por as Annotation nas propriedades, mas é apenas costume mesmo. Isso pode causar algum comportamento inesperado?

Comment: Ao realizar a modificação sugerida, e tentar gravar o Item usando o método 'Save' do controller é exibido esse erro a baixo:
"Type definition error: [simple type, class br.com.rpgnext.deck.critical.model.Card]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (java.util.Set) not compatible with managed type (br.com.rpgnext.deck.critical.model.Card)\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]"

Comment: @DouglasDreer Você está usando o Spring boot? Caso sim, qual versão? Senão estiver usando, qual a versão do Jackson?

Comment: estou sim usando SpringBoot, e a versão do Jackson eu não defini a versão, mas pus "jackson-databind"

Comment: @DouglasDreer Quanto as anotações nas propriedades: sim, você pode fazer, não a problema algum. O importante é manter um padrão, se você coloca as anotações nas propriedades, tente fazer assim em todas. Evite misturar anotações nos *Setters* e *Getters* com anotações nas propriedades.

Comment: @DouglasDreer Qual a versão do Spring boot?

Comment: SpringBoot 2.0-RELESE

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75789/discussion-between-douglas-dreer-and-felipe-marinho).